# persistent storage across different subdomains

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to figure out how to save data across different subdomains,
I've been researching this a lot and i'm about to give up.
The only solution that works is cookies because i can share them across subdomains but the problem is that those cookies (a bit large in size) sent on every http request to my server which causes issues with the header size.
other alternatives that i've found was the web storage (local storage/session storage ) but it's restricted with SOP , and using an embedded iframe and use postmessage to retrieve and write data is slow because the postmessage api is async which causes data retrieve/write to be slow.
I've tried setting the cookie "path" attribute to some random path and than inject an iframe with that random path and access the cookie via its contentDocument (No SOP restrictions) but again as soon as i append the iframe a network request to that path is executed and the huge header problem again... , I've also tried to use the window.history api to change the path of the document without requesting the new path but i can't access the new path cookies.
Any ideas / alternatives / before i'm giving up and switch to server side storage?

EDIT: i've also tried setting the "document.domain" to bypass the SOP restrictions but thats bad practise to load the main domain in every page just to be able to access its local storage.

Comment: Have you tried whether setting [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain) can help with the SOP issues when it comes to local/sessionStorage?

Comment: (If not, it should at least allow iframe access across the subdomain border, so that you would not have to use postMessage, but can access methods and properties of the document loaded into the iframe directly.)

Comment: @misorude i did read about it but that's a bit like using a bazooka to kill a fly , because i will actually load all the resources and the entire webpage of the main domain every time .

Comment: I don’t see the problem, it will only load what you tell it to load …? If you only want to load something from the main domain to be able to access its storage – well then _don’t_ load your full, main document with s-loads of external scripts, stylesheets and images embedded - but only a minimal document that contains only what you need for this purpose …?

Comment: @misorude you are right ,but i'm developing a third party js library that others will use so i don't have control over the users servers